# How to prevent Twitter Bootstrap changing margins as width of page is extended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was practising with the Bootstrap 3 css. I planed on having a fixed footer and a fixed navigation bar on my webpage. So to do this I used margins of 5% to make the content in the middle of my page to not be covered by the footer or header. To format the text I am using the `container` class which comes with bootstrap. This can be seen in the picture below.

[image]

This looked as it should. However I soon discovered that when the width of the page is expanded it increases the margin size. Like in the picture shown below.

[image]

So is there a way to limit how much the margins can extend on the `container` class in bootstrap. For example something similar too

```
.addThisClassToTagWithClassContainer {
     max-margin-top:5%;
     max-margin-bottom:5%;
     max-margin-left:5%;
     max-margin-right:5%;
}
```

There is a copy of the files [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_8jMDE7b51dYnJCYklVZEJMcWM&usp=sharing) if you believe this is a coding error that I have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly a bootstrap issue - when you set `padding` and `margin` as a % value, like in your example, the % is calculated from the width of the containing element.  If you want to set a fixed height, you can use `px`, or if you want it to be a consistent size relative to the height of the viewport instead, you can use `vh` (5vh is equal to 5/100 -- or 5% -- of the viewport height).

Typically, this would be a case for `px` simply because on a small screen, `5vh` could be very small, and usually a navbar, for instance, would stay a pretty consistent size regardless of how tall the window is.

So something like this is probably your most likely approach:

```
.page-body {
  margin-top: 100px; /* some number equal to the height of navbar */  
  margin-bottom: 150px; /* some number equal to the height of footer */  
}
```

But if you do actually want to have it be relative to the height of the window, you can do this (You will probably need a higher number than 5, here to make similar to your screenshot.):

```
.page-body {
  margin-top: 5vh;   
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}
```

You should find either approach will prevent your margins from changing when the width of the page changes.

Answer (score 1):

The container class is intentionally not 100% width. It is different fixed widths depending on the width of the viewport.

If you want to work with the full width of the screen, use `.container-fluid`:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```